# Welche dieser Wörter/Aussprüche sind tabu?

Tags: taboos

Nach dem "inneren Reichsparteitag", den Katrin Müller-Hohenstein bei der letzten Fußball-WM ausrief, wollte ich hier mal fragen, welche nazi-konnotierten Wörter/Redensarten haltet Ihr für "nicht mehr salonfähig", bzw. für immer noch gebräuchlich?

Ich meine Dinge wie eben diesen "inneren Reichsparteitag" oder Anmerkungen wie "jedem das Seine".

Comment: Ich zweifele, ob man die Frage vernünftig beantworten kann. Eine positive, abschließende Aufzählung auf diesem Gebiet dürfte unmöglich sein. Außerdem muss immer der Kontext beachtet werden. "[Jedem das seine](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedem_das_Seine)" ist Teil eines schon in der Antike geprägten Rechtsgrundsatzes; ob er im pervertierten Sinn gebraucht wird wie im "Dritten Reich", hängt vom Kontext ab. Der "innere Reichsparteitag" ist m.E. schon begrifflich Nonsens, da kommt also noch Gedankenlosigkeit dazu.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Sehe ich auch so. Das sollte ein community wiki werden.

Comment: Interessante Frage, aber wohl leider zu subjektiv, als dass man sie abschließend beantworten könnte.

Comment: Selbst zusammengesetzte Worte wie "Kruppstahl" können problematisch sein -- obwohl "Krupp" und "Stahl" an sich (hoffentlich) keine nazi-Assoziationen bewirken. "Krupphusten" ist wiederum kein Problem. Das soll einer verstehen...

Comment: Eine subjektive Einschätzung von einer paar Leuten würd mir schon genügen.

Comment: "jedem das Seine"? War mir neu, dass das eine Nazi-Konnotation hat (und ich benutze es durchaus)

Comment: "Jedem das Seine" stand über dem Tor am KZ Buchenwald - inwiefern der Spruch dadurch tabu geworden ist, ist [umstritten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedem_das_Seine#Verwendung_des_Begriffes_heute).

Comment: Weiß jemand was zu "Machtübernahme"?

Comment: zu "jedem das Seine" und "Machtübernahme": Wenn man es darauf anlegt, können wohl sehr viele Begriffe und Redensarten als "nazi-konnotiert" eingestuft werden.

Answer (score 6):

Das Wort **Endlösung** hat im Holocaust eine Rolle gespielt (["Endlösung der Judenfrage"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endl%C3%B6sung_der_Judenfrage)) und ist seitdem aus dem allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch verschwunden.

Wenn in Projekten über eine endgültige Lösung eines Problems gesprochen wird, wird dieser Begriff meist bewusst vermieden.

Answer (score 4):

Die *wirklich* problematischen Äußerungen sind solche, die der Allgemeinheit nicht mehr als Nazisprüche geläufig sind, aber von rechten Politikern als Codes an ihre Zielgruppe verwendet werden. So ist "Jedem das Seine" für mich nicht tabu, aber wenn es bei einer Diskussion über Internierungslager für Asylwerber aufkommt, ist es sehr problematisch.

Beispiele für Phrasen und Gesten, die mehr oder weniger tabu sind:

- *Unsere/meine Ehre heißt Treue.* (SS-Motto, die Verwendung ist laut Wikipedia in Österreich und Deutschland sogar strafbar, wurde 2000 von einem FPÖ-Politiker gesagt, der sich damit verteidigte, dass ihm der Spruch spontan eingefallen sei und er nicht wußte, dass es sich um einen SS-Spruch handelte. Das Problem ist, dass Leute aus dem entsprechenden Milieu mit solchen Sprüchen tatsächlich großgeworden sein können.)
- *Ostküste* als Bezeichnung für die (Regierung der) USA ist eine Chiffre für die Juden, die durch die USA die Weltpolitik manipulieren.
- *Arbeit macht frei.*
- *Zecken* (und ähnliche Worte für Ungeziefer) auf Menschen anwenden, wird aber immer wieder verwendet, vergleiche http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Zecken&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=0

Beispiele für Phrasen, die historisch keinen Bezug zur NS-Zeit haben, aber wegen der Assoziation mehr und mehr tabu sind:

- *durch den Rost fallen*
- *bis zur Vergasung lachen*

Comment: *Vergasung* hat keinen historischen Bezug zur NS-Zeit? Ich würde denken, das wäre sogar eine sehr beispielhafte Antwort auf die ursprüngliche Frage. Aber *durch den Rost fallen* verstehe ich nicht.

Comment: @fzwo: Ich möchte _durch den Rost fallen_ lieber nicht genauer erklären, aber versuche einfach, es sehr wörtlich zu nehmen. (Ich habe übrigens zuerst auch nicht verstanden, was thei meinen könnte.)

Comment: @fzwo: Google nach "lachen bis zur Vergasung". Ich halte die Poster, die sagen, dass diese Phrase schon vor der NS-Zeit verwendet wurde, für glaubwürdig. Bei der anderen Phrase hatte ich schon immer Zweifel, weil die Assoziation nicht sehr sinnig für die Bedeutung der Phrase ist.

Comment: @thei, @fzwo: Oder [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bis_zur_Vergasung); "Vergasung" wie in "Giftgas" aus dem 1. Weltkrieg klingt recht überzeugend.

Comment: @thei: Zecken ist mir persönlich sogar viel mehr als Eigenbezeichnung für Personen der linken Szene geläufig. Vgl. "schwul"

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt (bekommst Du eigentlich auch Benachrichtigungen, wenn ich nur @Hendrik schreibe?): OK, akzeptiert. Dennoch inakzeptable Wortwahl, weil eigentlich doch ziemlich zweitrangig ist, ob die Nazis oder irgendwelche Militärs im 1. Weltkrieg Leute mit Giftgas umgebracht haben. Ich sag ja auch nicht "Lachen bis die Twin Towers einstürzen".

Comment: @fzwo (@Hendrik reicht völlig; siehe [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/43019) für Details): Ja, Du hast völlig recht, "Vergasung" weckt ganz schlechte Assoziationen und sollte daher im Allgemeinen vermieden werden. Der Ursprung ist dabei in der Tat egal.

Comment: Lachen bis der Arzt kommt, sich totlachen - harsche Ausdrücke sind nicht selten. `Bis zur Vergasung` evoziert in mir auch primär Assoziationen zu Zyklon B, nicht zum 1. Weltkrieg, daher verzichte ich darauf. Umgekehrt würde ich aber aufgrund des Wissens niemanden für die Verwendung kritisieren. Bevor es jemand aber verwendet, wenn ich eine Rede oder Publikation gegenlesen würde, würde ich es aber wohl doch. Es käme auf den Kontext an.

Comment: Google-Ngram zeigt übrigens für "durch den Rost fallen" Peaks bei ca. 1855 und 1895, danach Flaute bis in die 1990. Dass die Phrase was mit der NS-Zeit zu tun haben soll ist mir völlig neu. Und für die Fragestellung ist es natürlich nicht zweitrangig, ob eine Konnotation wg. des Nationalsozialismus oder wg. Giftgas im 1. Weltkrieg tabu ist.

Answer (score 2):

Auch das Wort der politischen **Bewegung** ist schwierig.

Die NSDAP bezeichnete sich immer als "die Bewegung". Nach dem Krieg war es tabu. Erst die Grünen haben es dann wieder salonfähig gemacht - es hat aber, finde ich, trotzdem nach wie vor 'ein Gschmäckle'.

Comment: viele NGOs verstehen sich auch als politische Bewegungen…

Answer (score 2):

"Tschechei" als Ausdruck für Tschechien ist beleidigend, wie mir tschechische Bekannte mitgeteilt haben, und weckt für sie Assoziationen an "Zerschlagung der Rest-Tschechei".

Comment: Andererseits benutzt meine tschechische Großmutter nahezu immer den Begriff Tschechei.

Answer (score 1):

> Der größte XY aller Zeiten

geht wohl auf den Gröfaz, den größten Feldherrn aller Zeiten (eine Bezeichnung für Hitler) zurück, wird aber beliebter und beliebter, obwohl ja die Zukunft niemand vorhersagen kann, und somit nur 2 Zeiten, die Gegenwart und Vergangenheit beurteilt werden können.

Im allgemeinen Übertreibungswahn ist den meisten Leuten aber wurscht, wenn sie Blödsinn reden.

Ein Sporttrainer der

> zäh wie Leder, flink wie ein Windhund, hart wie Kruppstahl

verwendet würde auch schief angesehen. Verschiedene Begriffe würde man aber wohl heute auch dann nicht verwenden wollen, wenn sie nicht von den Nazis gebraucht worden wären

- Negermusik
- entartete Kunst
- Schmarotzer (schon genannt)
- Rassenschande

Abgesehen vom Kontext, der ja bei Krieg per se nicht harmlos ist, wird man sich vorsehen

- Blitzkrieg
- totaler Krieg (`wollt Ihr den totalen Krieg?`, Göbbels)

zu benutzen, und nur verwenden, wenn die Assoziation zum dt. Faschismus ausdrücklich erwünscht ist.

Comment: "Wollt Ihr den totalen Krieg?" - Geißler

Comment: Was soll der Kommentar sagen?

Comment: "Der größte XY aller Zeiten": Übertrieben und unbedacht? Sicher. Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch tabu? Eher nicht, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Was ich z.B. nicht wusste, ist dass das Zitat

> Ich aber beschloss, Politiker zu werden.

von Adolf Hitler stammt. Sollte vermieden werden.

Comment: Ist diese Antwort ironisch gemeint?

Comment: @Hendrik Nein, wusste ich wirklich nicht. Ich kannte das Zitat vorher nur vom hören sagen und bin dann selbst erstaunt gewesen, von wem es stammte. Quelle: [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_geflügelter_Worte/I#Ich_aber_beschloss.2C_Politiker_zu_werden.)

Comment: @FUZxxl: Oh, Entschuldigung, ich war nicht klar genug. Ich meinte den Teil "Sollte vermieden werden." (Dass Hitler das mal gesagt hat, wusste ich auch nicht wirklich, auch wenn ich es vielleicht mal gehört habe.)

Comment: @Hendrik Ich finde, dass dieses ziemlich gut in die hier beschriebe Kategorie passt. „Jedem das seine“ wirkt auch harmlos, wenn man den Kontext nicht kennt.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Hmm, es wird aber sehr schwierig werden sein, jedweden Ausspruch von Hitler zu vermeiden. "Jedem das seine" finde ich auch völlig harmlos. Ich bin gegen diese Vermeidungsstrategien. Bei "Arbeit macht frei" ist das etwas anderes.

Comment: Ja eben, es wäre auch total sinnlos. Vielleicht hat Hitler auch mal "Ich liebe dich" zu Eva Braun gesagt und sicher tausende völlig normale Sätze … da überhaupt auf die Idee zu kommen, all das vermeiden zu wollen, ist schon grotesk.

Comment: @FUZxx! Wie auf Wikipedia schon schon zu lesen ist: "[Der Ausspruch] wurde damit als Propagandaspruch **missbraucht**". Nazis haben bestimmt auch Brot gegessen, soll ich deshalb nun darauf verszichten?

Answer (score -1):

Man kann nicht alles vermeiden, was je ein Nazi gesagt hat, tatsächlich sind wir heute näher an der Nazi-Ideologie als wir glauben mögen, nur wird das ausgeblendet.

Wer weiß schon noch, daß "Gemeinnutz geht vor Eigennutz" (drastischere Form: "Du bist nichts, dein Volk ist alles.") eine beliebete Nazi-Phrase war?
Weiter: sprachlich unterscheiden wir zwar nicht mehr zwischen "raffendem" und "schaffendem" Kapital, wir nennen es heute "Finanzkapital" und "Realwirtschaft". Dennoch ist es gerade aktuell modisch, "internationale Spekulanten" (nur das "jüdische" fehlt), "Börsen-Casino" usw. für alles mögliche verantwortlich zu machen. Man könnte noch mehr dergleichen aufzählen.

Grund für all das ist, daß von interessierter Seite verschleiert wurde und wird, daß der Nationalsozialismus im Grunde eine antikapitalistische Bewegung war und ist. (Götz Aly hat hier dankenswerterweise mit seiner Forschung aufklärerisch gewirkt.)

Man darf weiterhin antikapitalistisch sein, nur die Identifikation von Kapital und Juden ist tabuisiert (und auch tatsächlich falsch).

Comment: Das wäre eine gute Antowrt auf die Frage: "Welche Begriffe haben einen Ursprung in der Rhetorik des dritten Reiches, und sie werden trotzdem immer noch verwendet?"

Comment: Das könnte jetzt eine lange Diskussion werden, wenn diese nicht unerwünscht wären (für Chat habe ich aber auch keine Zeit, jetzt). Ich möchte aber 2-3 Dingen widersprechen: Ich weiß nicht wieviel % des Preisaufschlags, den man für Fairtrade-Produkte zahlt, bei den Arbeitern vor Ort ankommt. Es ist aber eine klassifikation nach objektiven Kriterien, die in der Macht der Anbieter liegen - m.W. kann jeder, der die Kriterien erfüllt, das Fair-Trade-Siegel benutzen. Dagegen konnte ein Jude nicht seiner Religion abschwören, um dem Boykott zu entgehen.

Comment: Auf ähnliche Weise ist der Vergleich mit Finanz- und Realwirtschaft schief. Es ist auch keineswegs eine Neuigkeit, die Götz Aly entdeckt hätte. Die Untertützung der Nationalsozialisten durch die Großindustrie im 3. Reich ist gut dokumentiert. Die sozialistischen Bestrebungen der Nationalsozialisten waren nach der Wahl schnell vergessen, und mit dem sog. "Rhömputsch" vorbei. Außer jüdischen Vermögen wurde m.W. wenig enteignet (arisiert). Der Ns. war nicht im Grunde antikap., aber er hatte derartige Strömungen, die auch im Namen anklingen.

Comment: Ok, das mit dem fair trade nehmme ich zurück, es handelt sich in der Tat lediglich um eine recht wirksame (?) Marketing-Maßnahme, dennoch stört mich daran immer, daß insinuiert wird, normaler Handel sei (grundsätzlich) unfair.